# Jquery ajax method calling web service receiving 403 forbidden

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, json, web-services

I have a html page with the following ajax method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.webservice.com/blahblah.asmx/blahb123",
            data: "tnWsGuid=TEST1",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    alert("sucess")
                },
                error: function(e)
                {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(e));                       
                }
                });
        });
```

Which is returning to me 403 forbidden. A fellow co-worker built the web service and I do not have access to the code nor do I have the current ability to change it as he is on vacation. I need to display this data - at this point everything I try is failing and giving me a 403 forbidden error. I have changed the url name and the success function to just a alert dialog for the purpose of displaying the code.

One other thing is that the json is wrapped in XML it seems, coming from a ASP.NET webservice which looks like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://Walkthrough/XmlWebServices/">
{"approverName":"","emailAddress":"","companyName":"ABC","address":{"streetAddress1":"12 BlahBlah","streetAddress2":"","state":"ON","zipCode":"","country":"SO","phoneNumber":""},"tabledata:"[{"vendorPart":"AAAAA","partDescription":"N/A","price":"0.00","quantity":"28"},{"vendorPart":"BBBBBBB","partDescription":"N/A","price":"0.00","quantity":"3"},{"vendorPart":"CCCCCC","partDescription":"N/A","price":"0.00","quantity":"25"}]}
</string>
```

This was not the intention originally as I had expected to receive json however I can't do anything about it now and must deal with it in XML and just try and turn the json formatted inside into a json object.

I have tried as the following too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                url: "http://www.webservice.com/blahblah.asmx/blahb123",
                data: "tnWsGuid=TEST1",
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType: "text/xml",
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        alert("sucess")
                    },
                    error: function(e)
                    {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(e));                       
                    }
                    });
            });
```

Finally I will output the Firebug response from FireFox here for both examples I've tried (json/xml)

Json: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZHUg.jpg

XML: http://i.imgur.com/6qiGVwQ.jpg

Thank you very much for reading!

Comment: Debugging a web service to determine why it is rejecting your requests is really hard without access to that webservice.

Comment: Based on the very limited information you've provided, it would appear that the service doesn't grant permission for JS on other origins to access it. There is no way you can make browsers on your site read the data from the service. Move (at least some of) your logic server side.

Comment: I am trying to reach out to this individual, if I were able to get access to the web service what particularly can I do to enable the granting of this permission?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS  (deleted wikipedia link as it doesn't mention the preflight check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well removing the contentType header seem's to remove the 403 forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

If the call is cross domain you may encounter issues if you don't use the dataType jsonp.

Comment: On chrome I do get the cross domain issue error in the console after the 403 forbidden. However jsonp requires I change the webservice right? I also thought of attempting to use jsonp however two problems, one the returned data is in xml not json and I cannot effectively change the web service to handle jsonp requests.